# Remove hacked URLs from Google Search

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, hacked-site

My client's site shows "This site may be hacked" in Google's search result.

I restored the website, installed security plugins, scanned and removed all possible issues and requested Google for a review.

It got rejected with the following message:

> We are seeing content on your site that we believe is injected by a
>   hacker. The content may be cloaked, meaning that Google sees different
>   content than what’s being shown to you or your visitors. You can use
>   'Fetch as Google' in Search Console to see the content that we are
>   seeing. Learn about cloaking and 'Fetch as Google' here:
>   https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2604723.
>
> Here is an
>   example of hacked content on your site:
>
> "That. A pizza pie. Wants to
>   complete three sources of day."
>   (`http://example.com/how-to-write-book-report-5th-grade/`)

The URL Google says is hacked is non-existent, I did a further search to see how Google has indexed the website using this URL and I can see a lot of non-existent URLs, perhaps which was injected a while back which is cleaned now.

I want to know

- How do I ask Google to remove all non-existent URL
- Re-index the website
- Lastly remove the message "This site may be hacked"

Comment: Did you checked every part of site and upgraded everything ?

Comment: Yes i did, as i said the URL reported from google does not even exist.

Comment: We have tackled this scenario here many times. However, for your sake, I will tell you this. If your site is on a shared server, it is possible that another site can effect yours if the shared server is not set-up correctly. As well, make sure that all software is up to date including plug-ins and themes. You can check them here: https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/search?execution=e2s1 Also run an anti-virus against the hard-drive including rootkit. It is also possible that a virus outside of your site effects your site in real-time with intelligence enough to know Google versus users.

Comment: Google and other search engines are notoriously slow. It can take a while for these things to clear. As well, Google gets notification from other sites, blacklists, and anti-virus (indirectly) so it is possible that Google did not actually see a problem. Also keep in mind that errors occur. For example, Google told me yesterday that my site links to a porn site. It does not. It cannot. It does not link out. Additionally, the page in question referred to a site that no longer exists. This means that mistakes are made and false alarms do exist.

Comment: Review the HTTP logs and look for requests made by Google (via user-agent). This should give you an idea of what they're seeing and you could even try recreating those requests by impersonating the user-agent to be Google. Note that restoring content may restore the vulnerability that was exploited. Need to identify the core issue which is why reviewing Google's requests is important.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to send in a reconsideration request through google webmaster tools.  There should be a message there telling you how to correct the issue and allowing you to remove the flag.  Usually this take about 72 hours.  You will need to provide google with the steps you took to prevent this hack in the future.  Continued hacks may hurt your reputation in the long term.

Search your site in google using the flag site:yourwebsite.com  find each link you want to remove from the search engine and put that google webmaster tools Google Index > Remove Urls's  this will usually take effect pretty quickly, but you will have to do each manual URL you want removed.  If you already have a list of urls, simply copy and past them in there as well.